Error connect office365 with Webklex Laravel 11
I am trying to connect to Office 365 to retrieve emails.
I am using the Webklex library version 4.1.
I am able to obtain the authentication token to log into the email, but I always receive 'connection setup failed'.
This is how I capture the authentication token.
private function getToken0Auth()
{
    try {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        // Solicitar o token do endpoint de OAuth2 do Microsoft
        // laravel office
        $response = $client->post('https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.env('tenant_id').'/oauth2/v2.0/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => env('client_id'),
                'client_secret' => env('client_secret'),
                'scope' => 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default',
                'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            ],
        ]);
        $body = json_decode($response->getBody());
        if (!$body->access_token) {
            return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Não foi possivel gerar o token.'];
        }
        return ['success' => true, 'token' => $body->access_token];
    } catch (\Throwable $t) {
        return ['success' => false, 'message' => $t->getMessage()];
    }
}

This is an example of the token response:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6InNjUWJVeERrY3BvcjNsdVdaa080OERISDNsSDQwSmhEVk5QeXlVanBBb1EiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ikg5bmo1QU9Tc3dNcGhnMVNGeDdqYVYtbEI5dyIsImtpZCI6Ikg5bmo1QU9Tc3dNcGhnMVNGeDdqYVYtbEI5dyJ9.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.iZYBRa448-6E0oGNJU4FcXoeiDuhLTgDBQSMmJ-kyY1cOtsf3YHtl3b2HCYcRnanxLSa1v8WHxV2VR0KUH_FRUnDhAIVmHxztt039YvB3mk1znVXB7er6wDK_w07xRxH6ftvqo3ia8KPzXQXYGJ4iz2E8NyJYFlp8J_aj76fK2OncxHnTYe5HxyEkqWN50IKCTDoSFL_bEhmNLRhhAXm6O5od81KVC0sGz8BbhBD-QTLnoZRptb3SG1KTc0H-_uRvO8qAWYpwu3XCzNCETmiIuVVSyDUjafh6CinW8sAVm9kuBCtPpetzoYbljQlLjVyfE5Ppha8DmdFj2xtTYS4XA
After capturing the token, I use this function to connect to the IMAP server:
$oClient = Client::make([
    'host'          => 'outlook.office365.com',
    'port'          => 993,
    'encryption'    => 'ssl',
    'validate_cert' => false,
    'username'      => 'my-email',
    'password'      => $response['token'], // Token OAuth2
    'protocol'      => 'imap',
    'authentication' => 'oauth', // Definindo para autenticação OAuth
]);
$oClient->connect();

However, it always falls into the catch block, returning the same error: "connection setup failed"
In my Office 365 account, I had to register an app and grant permissions for access via IMAP.AccessAsApp
enter image description here
I also enabled IMAP for my mailbox.
enter image description here
Access to this application was created for any account.
I'm out of options at this point.

Connection setup failed?  Are you sure you're not being blocked by a firewall?  Have you tried another app or even a socket testing tool to make sure you can get through?

@Max I haven't tried connecting to another app, but I believe it's not a firewall block since I can successfully capture the token.

The token service uses HTTPS (443), IMAPS uses port 993 which is blocked on a lot of corporate networks.  They are also on different hosts!

use this scope https://outlook.office.com/.default
